# Comparing data with opposite distributions

Tags: nonparametric, speech-recognition

What test can I use to compare whether the difference between the following sets of data are significant. [image]

[image]

I know, I can just look at them, but I'd like it to be a bit more scientific than that. The data represents the number of times (0-5) speech recognition systems tracked each of the 350 words in a passage correctly. There were two sound files with noise at different frequencies.

Comment: Why do you think that looking at plots is less scientific than a (null hypothesis significance) test? I'd much rather look at the plots than some report claiming $p \leq \alpha$ where $\alpha=0.05$  (cause why bother with a non-arbitrary threshold). (¬_¬)

Comment: My favorite professor in grad school (Herman Friedman) would say this passes the IOTT. That's interocular trauma test. It hits you between the eyes. 

But .... If you want something fancy .... You could do Poisson regression with number of times as the DV and frequency as the IV.

Comment: I tend to agree with this; it's just that this is part of a thesis, so I wanna make it as bullet-proof as possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a hypothesis test, I would suggest reading more on the [Kruskal-Wallis test (KW)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%E2%80%93Wallis_one-way_analysis_of_variance). It is 'essentially' a non-parametric version of ANOVA, which is important as this data is almost certainly not normal/Gaussian. This ignores some basic facts about the data (e.g. we know its support is the set of discrete values $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$), but should get the job done.

[EDIT] Keep in mind that in the case of two competing samples, the two hypotheses you are testing are given by:

> $H_0 = $ All samples have identical distribution function
> $H_1 = $ The two samples differ only with respect to location / median.

[[taken from (Vidakovic, p. 900)]](https://web.stat.tamu.edu/%7Ebrani/statbook/)

This comes with the assumption that the distributions are 'generally' the same shape ([maybe Beta distributed?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution#)), but are different with respect to location. I can't be totally sure without learning more context, but it would seem like KW is a good fit for your use case. Rejecting the null, then, would indicate that one language system is 'better' than the other at tracking words. This is where the talk of stochastic dominance comes in to play, but at this point, we are talking about using a sledgehammer on a nail. If your only goal is to say "the two graphs are different", then KW should be okay.

Comment: I advise against this approach, although I can appreciate that it is common practice. The original poster (OP) is interested in a difference between the two sets, but the KW test better quantifies a form of stochastic dominance. These are related notions, but you might as well test the thing you actually want to test rather than a proxy. See my blog post [*Wilcoxon's Heuristic*](https://galenseilis.github.io/posts/wilcoxons-heuristic/) for some more details.

Comment: @Galen fair point. OP said he was interested in testing the 'differences in data', which is fairly broad. KW has the null hypothesis that the two population medians are the same. It is up to OP to decide whether or not that is what he was hoping for.

Comment: Re (your edits): If you're looking for a null hypothesis significance test that generically tests that two data distributions are *distinct* then I think the [two-sample KS Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test#Two-sample_Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) is more appropriate than the KW test.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies; I'm gonna look into that.